# NSPredicate query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I have used NSPredicate before but for different purpose. But I am stuck in following scenario for query.

I have array Persons which contains Person Objects i.e Persons is array of objects. I need to collect all names_ from all person objects from persons array. I know we can do it through for loop but can we do it through NSpredicate or more optimize way?

```
NSMutableArray *names;
for (int i=0; i<[persons count]; i++)
{
   [names addObject:[[persons objectAtIndex:i] names_]];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one line would do,

```
[PersonArray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.name"]
```

Comment: @cmk Ya, you got it. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: @"@ can be confusing to type. :) Thanks for updating it.